# Apache htaccess file, where did I go wrong?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Really can't find my mistake, I can access the sitemap/ link, but all the others give a 404 Not Found Error.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php?page=home index.php?page=error
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # some other stuff #

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^sitemap/?$ sitemap.xml.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^products/?$ index.php?page=products [L]
    RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=products&id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'd really appreciate some help, I definitely suck at .htaccess files...

Comment: Check your error log — what is showing up?

Comment: Same line a certain number of times :`[Wed Jul 04 02:56:30 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/home"`

Comment: Then… Are you sure the issue lies with your .htaccess file?

Comment: No, I'm really starting to think the issue may come from my Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting rules aside, you have other problems here:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php?page=home index.php?page=error
```

This means, that, for a folder a **file** showing index will be selected in this order (first one existing wins):

1. `index.php`
2. `index.php?page=home` (this is the **filename**)
3. `index.php?page=error` (this is the **filename**)

I doubt this was your intention.

Next:

```
AllowOverride All
```

If you're already in `.htaccess` and `AllowOverride` was restrictive, this will not help, and if it wasn't, then there is no point of writing this again.

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

This basically says "allow everyone everywhere" which is the default anyway. Unless it was restricted in some way on upper level or in apache configuration, this is redundant.

---

As for rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/?$ index.php?page=products [L]
```

The second rule is redundant anyway, and will never be reached (as the first one matches it as well).

---

As for the error you're seeing:

```
[Wed Jul 04 02:56:30 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/home"
```

This may mean problems with `DocumentRoot` definitions. Please, post your `VirtualHosts` configuration.